# How to change audio volume level for only Spotify alone on Android?

Tags: android, audio, spotify, volume

**As I change audio volume on my device, Spotify changes it's volume as well.**

However, I want to *lower the audio volume of Spotify alone*, is there any tricks to do that?

Infact, computer version of Spotify has a sweet **slider** at the bottom right side of player, which lets me adjust volume for Spotify *ONLY*!

[image: Spotify-Slider-Does-Not-Let-Me-Change-Volume-For-Only-Spotify-Alone]

Comment: Unless Spotify chooses to implement that sweet slider on mobile in the same fashion as it is in the desktop version, we're out of luck. [This](https://www.xda-developers.com/app-volume-control-individual-volume-levels-android/) may be interesting to you. Considering all this, I don't think this is a programming question in scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by using the sound equalizer. Spotify > Settings > playback > Equalizer.

Turn on the equalizer and manually set the line graph to bottom. It doesn’t effectively help but it does the trick.